# MSVC++ "official" arbitrary precision library

Tags: visual-c++, arbitrary-precision

I'm looking for an MSVC++ specific arbitrary precision library.  Since I don't need cross platform compatibility for what I'm working, I'd rather not have the mess of it all.

I tried looking at [NTL](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/) but upon seeing statements like "[These steps work with MSVC++ v6](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/doc/tour-win.html)" I can't help but mentally bury it as out of date.  Latest build:  `2009 08 14`.

[MPIR](http://mpir.org/) looks promising (latest build `2011 06 14`), its the best thing I found so far.

Any suggestions for doing *at least* 128-bit floating point arithmetic from MSVC++ (native code, not .NET)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[MPIR](http://mpir.org/) is the best C++ multi-precision (arbitrary precision) arithmetic library available right now. The fact that it is cross-platform is a plus.  It is easy to compile on MSVC++ 2010, you just have to make sure to open README.TXT (that comes with the download) and also read [the Documentation](http://mpir.org/mpir-2.4.0.pdf), (which is quietly listed as the 3rd download in the list but is actually quite good).

It is based on [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) and supercedes [NTL](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/), which should be all but abandoned because its not being maintained.

MPIR has builds and assembly code for a **large** number of CPUs, including like a ton of Intel and AMD chips.

One hitch I encountered in the build process (on 2 separate machines!) was the CPU type was not identified correctly.  On one machine I had a "k102" processor (which can be considered "k10") and on another machine I had "westmere" (which could be considered as "nehalem").  Anyway the fix is **BROWSE CONFIGURATION.BAT** and look for your CPU type.  When you invoke "configure.bat", use a line like:

```
configure --cpu-k10
```

If you know you have an AMD k10 compatible CPU.  This happened with a AMD 1090T processor.

Answer (score 0):

MPIR can be compiled with Visual Studio 2017.

Brian Gladman maintains a fork of MPIR that builds nicely with Visual Studio:
https://github.com/BrianGladman/mpir

```
# Open a "Visual Studio x64 Native Tools Prompt"
cd C:\github
git clone https://github.com/BrianGladman/mpir
cd mpir\msvc\vs17
msbuild gc lib x64 release
```

Also try running the `gen_*.bat` files in that same directory if this does not work.

It will also need a Windows SDK.

Brian also maintains a fork of MPFR that builds under Visual Studio:
https://github.com/BrianGladman/mpfr

Boost also includes C++ bindings for MPFR and GMP multi-precision libraries. Boost is well-maintained and will compile without much trouble within any version of Visual Studio.